# How to pass a docker image as argument in perl script

Tags: docker, perl

I am new to the docker world. I created a docker image to run samtools. I have a perl script that executes samtools and the variable looks like:

```
my $SAMTOOLS_BIN = "samtools";
```

In this case, the version of samtools installed in the system is executed.

Is there a way that I can pass the docker image as variable instead?

```
my $SAMTOOLS_BIN = "docker_image";
```

Comment: Without seeing the script, we can't help you much. What does it do with the variable?

Comment: The variable is used to execute samtools:
`system_p( $SAMTOOLS_BIN, "sort", '-@', 6, "-f", $bam_fn, $sortbam_fn );`
Basically, I want to run my perl script with a different version of samtools than the one installed in the system.So, I thought of creating a docker image for samtools and pass the docker image as variable. I was thinking if there is a way of running this docker image inside the perl script.

Comment: `system_p` is not a standard Perl function. Generally, though, it should be possible to run anything you can run from the command line.

Comment: I am not sure how this can be done with docker images though- if possible. I have not found anything similar.

Comment: If the command you want to run is packaged in a Docker image, you can’t run it directly, and you’ll need root-equivalent permissions to launch a container that could run it.  I’d prefer running the version on the host if you can.

Comment: Can you run it from the command line?

Comment: I will run it from the command line first. Thank you. I had not fully understood the concept of dockers but I am getting there.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, you can use a number of mechanisms to run external programs (the `system` command, backticks and `open()` for example). I assume that your `system_p()` subroutine uses one of these approaches.

Anything that you can run as a command on your shell's command line can be started using these mechanisms in Perl. You just need to work out what the correct command is.

The command that you use to run a Docker container will probably be `docker run [container_name]` (followed by some options). Once you've worked out exactly which options you need then it's just a case of passing that string to the `system()` command (or whatever mechanism you're using).

I assume you're getting your Docker image from the Docker Hub. There are a number of samstools images available from there so I'm not sure which one you're using. But it's likely that the page about the image you're using (e.g. [biocontainers/samtools](https://hub.docker.com/r/biocontainers/samtools/)) will have useful information on how to run it.